# How to properly use wp.ajax.post?

Tags: ajax, javascript

After struggling for quiet while with the wp utils functions send and post. I didn't manage to get one of them working properly after all.

But I did manage to get a response, however I don't know why this works and the other things I tried didn't.

For this topic, the PHP is not relevant. To prevent any confusions, consider I'm using the following PHP:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_example_action', function() {
   if (!empty($_REQUEST['foo'])) {
       print 'Foo: '.$_REQUEST['foo'];
   }
   wp_die();
});
```

The javascript what ALWAYS returned all the printed/echoed text in the triggered php function, no matter what conditions were met.

```
$('.some-button').click(function(e)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.wp.ajax.send('example_action', {
        data: { foo: $('.some-field').val() },
        error: function( response ) {
            console.log(response)
        }
});
```

Here the result of a simple test:

```
|================================================|
| $('.some-field').val() | console.log(response) |
|------------------------|-----------------------|
| "bar"                  | "Foo: bar"            |
| ""                     | "Foo: "               |
|================================================|
```

I tried a lot of things with the `send()` method as well as with the `post()` method. But nothing seems to work unless it's exactly like the javascript above. Yes it only works with property `error` not with `done` or `success` neither with `fail` or `always`.

---

#### Edit #1

Have a look at the following code where I explain what happens with the code that doesn't return a response.

```
let post = window.wp.ajax.post('example_action', { foo: $('.some-field').val() });

console.log(post);
// logs: {state: ƒ, always: ƒ, then: ƒ, promise: ƒ, pipe: ƒ, ...}

post.done(function(v) {
    // won't be executed
    console.log(v);
});
```

However in the network section of my developer tool the request and response are correctly shown.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the javascript code that isn't working?

Comment: and what is being actually sent (look in the network section of the browser developer tools)

Comment: @czerspalace please have a look at the code in the first edit of my question.

Comment: @Fleuv review my sample code, which i have added, all ready i worked on it.

Answer (score 3):

`wp.ajax.post` will need you to wrap your response with `wp_send_json_success`. It will add additional parameter on your json response with success flag.

Comment: I was using wp_send_json() and getting no response in js, I switched to wp_send_json_success() and it works!